# Merge two annotated results into one dictionary

Tags: django, dictionary, django-queryset, annotate

I have to annotated results:

```
cred_rec = Disponibilidad.objects.values('mac__mac', 'int_mes').annotate(tramites=Count('fuar'), recibidas=Count('fecha_disp_mac')
cred14   = Disponibilidad.objects.filter(int_disponible__lte=14).values('mac__mac', 'int_mes').annotate(en14=Count('fuar'))
```

Both have the same keys `'mac__mac'` and `'int_mes'`, what I want is to create a new dictionary with the keys in `cred_red`, plus `en14` from `cred14`.

I try some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720966/django-how-to-merge-two-related-querysets-in-django-0-96) [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945912/how-to-get-the-difference-of-two-querysets-in-django), but I missing something.

Thanks.

**EDIT.** After some tries and errors, I got this:

```
for linea in cred_rec:
  clave = (linea['mac__mac'], linea['int_mes'])
  for linea2 in cred14:
    clave2 = (linea2['mac__mac'], linea2['int_mes'])
    if clave2 == clave:
      linea['en14'] = linea2['en14']
      linea['disp'] = float(linea2['en14'])/linea['recibidas']*100
```

Now, I have to ask for a better solution. Thanks again.

=======
**EDIT**
This is how the input looks like:

```
fuar, mac_id, int_mes, int_disponible, int_exitoso, fecha_tramite, fecha_actualiza_pe, fecha_disp_mac
1229012106349,1,7,21,14,2012-07-02 08:33:54.0,2012-07-16 17:33:21.0,2012-07-23 08:01:22.0
1229012106350,1,7,25,17,2012-07-02 09:01:25.0,2012-07-19 17:45:57.0,2012-07-27 17:45:59.0
1229012106351,1,7,21,14,2012-07-02 09:15:12.0,2012-07-16 19:14:35.0,2012-07-23 08:01:22.0
1229012106352,1,7,24,16,2012-07-02 09:25:19.0,2012-07-18 07:52:18.0,2012-07-26 16:04:11.0
... a few  thousand lines dropped ...
```

The `fuar` is like an order_id; `mac__mac` is like the `site_id`, mes is `month`; `int_disponible` is the timedelta between `fecha_tramite` and `fecha_disp_mac`; `int_exitoso` is the timedelta between `fecha_tramite` and `fecha_actualiza_pe`.

The output is like this:

```
mac, mes, tramites, cred_rec, cred14,  % rec,  % en 14
1, 7, 2023, 2006, 1313, 99.1596638655, 65.4536390828
1, 8, 1748, 1182, 1150, 67.6201372998, 97.2927241963
2, 8, 731, 471, 441, 64.4322845417, 93.6305732484
3, 8, 1352, 840, 784, 62.1301775148, 93.3333333333
```

- *tramites* is the sum of all orders (`fuar`) in a month
- *cred_rec* cred is our product, in theory for each *fuar* there is a *cred*, `cred_rec` is the sum of all cred produced in a month
- *cred_14* is the sum of all cred made in 14 days
- *% rec* the relationship between fuar received and  cred produced, in %
- *% en 14* is the relationship between the cred produced and the cred produced in time

I will use this table in a [Annotated Time Line](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#annotated_time_line) chart or a [Combo Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#combo_chart) from Google Charts to show the performance of our manufacturation process.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What does your input look like, and what do you want your output to look like?

Comment: Question edited with the info.

Comment: The output talks about both "a month" and "14 days". How should we handle this?

Comment: `14 days` is the number of products made in 14 days. We a have a certain number of order in a month and we have to fullfill them in 14 days or less, that's our quality objectve. We must know how many orders we complete in 14 days and what percentage represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One immediate improvement to the current code you have would be to have the en14 and disp values precalculated and indexed by key. This will reduce the scans on the cred14 list, but will use memory to store the precalculated values.

```
def line_key(line):
      return (line['mac__mac'], line['int_mes'])

cred14_calcs = {}
for line in cred14:
  cred14_calcs[line_key(line)] = {
      'en14': line['en14'],
      'disp': float(line['en14'])/line['recibidas']*100
    }

for line in cred_rec:
  calc = cred14_calcs.get(line_key(line))
  if calc:
    line.update(calc)
```